# Simplifying this code sample to reduce the number of lines

Tags: kotlin

Is there a more concise way in Kotlin to reduce the number of lines of code in this sample:

```
    // A qualifier will always be provided and one of the
    // when selections will be chosen.

    when (qualifier) {
        QualifierConfiguration.MCCAndMNC -> {
            if (composableResource.mcc == null) {
                resources.removeAt(index)
                return true
            }
        }
        QualifierConfiguration.LanguageAndRegion -> {
            if (composableResource.languageAndRegion == null) {
                resources.removeAt(index)
                return true
            }
        }
        QualifierConfiguration.LayoutDirection -> {
            if (composableResource.layoutDirection == null) {
                resources.removeAt(index)
                return true
            }
        }
    }

    return false
```

I've only shown 3 items. In the real code there are a lot more and I want to avoid repeating similiar lines of code. Removing line breaks is not what I would consider reducing the number of lines. Looking more for a pattern.

Comment: When do you return false? I think knowing that can potentially make it even shorter.

Comment: When none of the when clauses are met, false is returned. NOTE: The qualifier variable is always provided.  There is no "else" clause in the when statement. So one of the when conditions will always be selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice and simple way:

```
if (when(qualifier) {
    QualifierConfiguration.MCCAndMNC -> composableResource.mcc
    QualifierConfiguration.LanguageAndRegion -> composableResource.languageAndRegion
    QualifierConfiguration.LayoutDirection -> composableResource.layoutDirection
} == null) { resources.removeAt(index); true } else false
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use scoped functions.

In your when, just return the composableResource.
With the ?let you ensure that you have a non-null composableResource so you can do any treatment you want

In the run, you are in a scope where your composableResource is null.
So here, you can remove your resource and return true.

It reduce slightly the number of lines and you get rid of code duplication (removeAt + return true).

```kotlin
when (qualifier) {
        QualifierConfiguration.MCCAndMNC -> 
            composableResource.mcc
        QualifierConfiguration.LanguageAndRegion -> 
            composableResource.languageAndRegion
        QualifierConfiguration.LayoutDirection -> 
            composableResource.layoutDirection
    }
    ?.let {
        false
    }
    ?: run {
        resources.removeAt(index)
        true
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is:

```
when (qualifier) {
    QualifierConfiguration.MCCAndMNC -> composableResource.mcc
    QualifierConfiguration.LanguageAndRegion -> composableResource.languageAndRegion
    QualifierConfiguration.LayoutDirection -> composableResource.layoutDirection
    // else -> return false // uncomment if there are missing cases in the "when"
}.let { x -> // I suggest that you rename "x" to something appropriate in your context
    if (x == null) {
        resources.removeAt(index)
        true
    } else {
        false
    }
}
```